# Rotating Wheel with rotating icons

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-canvas

Now these days i am working on Rotating wheel likely attached screenshot.

[image]

[image]

I've found code from [github https://github.com/R4md4c/AndroidRotaryWheelView](https://github.com/R4md4c/AndroidRotaryWheelView)
The difficulty is that i am not able to keep icons in vertical position during rotation of the wheel. Icons being rotated in form of its Wheel's Segment While it is required to keep them in vertical position as they are being displayed initially (as per screenshot-1).

I have to customize the following code where i need to change the Bounds for particular drawable's rect.

I find myself unable to achieve the exact calculation in the reference.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
    @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
// set the height of Wheel childs items
    canvas.scale(getWidth() / mViewRect.width(), getHeight() / 2
            / mViewRect.width(), xPosition, yPosition);


    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG); // Saving the canvas and later
                                            // restoring it so only this
                                            // image will be rotated.
    canvas.rotate((float) mRotationAngle, xPosition, yPosition);

    for (int i = 0; i < mWedges.length; i++) {
        Wedge f = mWedges[i];
        mPaint.setColor(SEGMENT_COLOR);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        canvas.drawPath(f, mPaint);

        Rect rf = iconRect[i];

        if ((mMenuEntries.get(i).getIcon() != 0)
                && (mMenuEntries.get(i).getLabel() != null)) {

            System.out.println("the canvasd drawn ........");

            // This will look for a "new line" and split into multiple lines
            String menuItemName = mMenuEntries.get(i).getLabel();
            String[] stringArray = menuItemName.split("\n");

            mPaint.setColor(textColor);

            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            // mPaint.setTextSize(textSize);

            Rect rect = new Rect();
            float textHeight = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
                mPaint.getTextBounds(stringArray[j], 0,
                        stringArray[j].length(), rect);
                textHeight = textHeight + (rect.height() + 3);
            }

            Rect rf2 = new Rect();
            rf2.set(rf.left, rf.top - ((int) textHeight / 2), rf.right,
                    rf.bottom - ((int) textHeight / 2));

            float textBottom = rf2.bottom;
            for (int j = 0; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
                mPaint.getTextBounds(stringArray[j], 0,
                        stringArray[j].length(), rect);
                float textLeft = rf.centerX() - rect.width() / 2;
                textBottom = textBottom + (rect.height() + 3);
                mPaint.setTextSize(scalePX(8));
                canvas.drawText(stringArray[j], textLeft - rect.left,
                        textBottom - rect.bottom, mPaint);
            }

            // canvas.rotate((float)mRotationAngle,
            // rf.top-((int)textHeight/2), rf.bottom-((int)textHeight/2));
            int index = checkSelection(canvas);
            rf2 = rotaionRf(rf2, mRotationAngle);


            if (i == index) {
                // Puts in the Icon
                Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(
                        mMenuEntries.get(i).getIconSelected());
                drawable.setBounds(rf2);
                drawable.draw(canvas);

            } else {
                // Puts in the Icon
                Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(
                        mMenuEntries.get(i).getIcon());
                drawable.setBounds(rf2);
                drawable.draw(canvas);
            }
            // Icon Only
        } else if (mMenuEntries.get(i).getIcon() != 0) {

            System.out.println("the canvasd drawn ELSE........");

            // Puts in the Icon
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(
                    mMenuEntries.get(i).getIconSelected());
            drawable.setBounds(rf);

            drawable.draw(canvas);

            // Text Only
        } else {
            // Puts in the Text if no Icon
            mPaint.setColor(this.textColor);

            /*
             * if (f != enabled && Wedge2Shown == true) {
             * mPaint.setAlpha(disabledAlpha); } else {
             * mPaint.setAlpha(textAlpha); }
             */
            // mPaint.setAlpha(textAlpha);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            // mPaint.setTextSize(textSize);

            // This will look for a "new line" and split into multiple lines
            String menuItemName = mMenuEntries.get(i).getLabel();
            String[] stringArray = menuItemName.split("\n");

            // gets total height
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            float textHeight = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
                mPaint.getTextBounds(stringArray[j], 0,
                        stringArray[j].length(), rect);
                textHeight = textHeight + (rect.height() + 3);
            }

            float textBottom = rf.centerY() - (textHeight / 2);
            for (int j = 0; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
                mPaint.getTextBounds(stringArray[j], 0,
                        stringArray[j].length(), rect);
                float textLeft = rf.centerX() - rect.width() / 2;
                textBottom = textBottom + (rect.height() + 3);
                canvas.drawText(stringArray[j], textLeft - rect.left,
                        textBottom - rect.bottom, mPaint);

            }

            // canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, hOffset, vOffset, paint)
            // canvas.rotate((float)mRotationAngle, xPosition, yPosition );
            // canvas.drawRect(rf, mPaint);

        }
        // canvas.restore();
    }
    // canvas.restore();
    canvas.restore();

    // System.out.println()
    canvas.save();

    canvas.restore();


    mPaint.setShader(mShader);
    // mPaint.setAlpha(0x66);
    // Draw the Selection Segment
    if (mSelectionWedge != null) {
        canvas.drawPath(mSelectionWedge, mPaint);
        // canvas.drawRect(mSelectionWedge.getWedgeRegion().getBounds(),
        // mPaint);
    }

    mPaint.setShader(null);



    int index = checkSelection(canvas);

    System.out.println("the index=====" + index);

    if (checkSelection(canvas) != -1) {
    }
}
```

Comment: post your answer in this bounty qtn..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826982/rotate-images-around-a-circle

Answer (score 0):

on using canvas.rotate u have to make sure the x&y values u give it are the MAIN wheel center.